# How to get my public Ip rather than server Ip in python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

```
import socket
a= socket.getfqdn()
b= socket.gethostbyname(a)
print(b)
```

If I run this code on any website, I get my Ip on that server, but is it possible to make it show public Ip even when I run it on website?

Comment: Does that server even have a public IP (or is it behind a proxy/load-balancer)?